# How to add menu items to system.admin_content parent?

Tags: 8

`parent: system.admin_content` route handles `/admin/content` path. I'm trying to add more items to the menu tabs visible on that page.

[image: /admin/conntent]

So I'm doing this:

```
# test.routing.yml
entity.admin.test:
  path: '/admin/content/test_entity'
  defaults:
    _entity_list: 'test_entity'
    _title: 'Test entities'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer content types'

# test.links.menu.yml
test.admin:
  title: Test entities
  route_name: entity.admin.test
  # I have also tried using route defined in my entity type annotation
  # route_name: entity.test_entity.collection
  parent: system.admin_content
  description: 'List and edit site test entities.'
```

The route works (I can access page at `/admin/content/test_entity`), but menu item is not displayed. If I change parent to for example `system.admin_structutre` then the menu item is shown on `/admin/structure` list without problems.

Comment: do u want it to appear on the admin main page or within the content options ?? @Silicon

Comment: @make-me-alive I want it to appear as a tab on `/admin/content` page next to "Content" and "Files" tabs as shown on the image that I've attached.

Answer (score 1):

> `Dont` use `test.links.menu.yml` instead use `test.links.task.yml`

in `test.links.task.yml` try the below code...

```
entity.admin.test:
  title: 'Test entities'
  route_name: entity.admin.test
  description: 'List and edit site test entities.'
  base_route: system.admin_content
```

Comment: Didn't help. But comment module that I checked is also using `*.links.menu.yml` instead of `tasks`.

Comment: can u also see this link @SiliconMind
[link]https://www.drupal.org/node/2122253

Comment: Comment module has menu AND task file: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/tree/9.0.x/core/modules/comment. What you want is local tabs defined in task file.